# German date Localization without the dot?

Tags: angular, date, localization, format

When using a date pipe in Angular with a german localized weekday, a dot / full stop  is automatically added behind the weekday.

```
<span>{{ day | date:'EE'}}</span>
```

Should look like this `Mo`, `Di`, `Mi`
Actually looks like this: `Mo.`, `Di.`, `Mi.`

Is it possible to use the pipe without it adding the dot?
If I wanted to add punctuation I would do so in the formatting string.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Not nice but a workaround for german "dots" is:

```
{{(day | date : 'EE')?.replace('.','')}}
```